# site title inside the suite bar will be shown in the right side of the screen

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css

I have modified my master page to move the site collection title from the body, to be inside my upper suite bar. So I move the following `h1` div code to be inside the Suite bar DIV as follow:-

```
<div id="suiteLinksBox">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteLinksDelegate" ControlId="SuiteLinksDelegate" runat="server" />
</div>

<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle" style="color:white;float:left"">
      <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
                  runat="server"
                  RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                      SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
                  CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">
            <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
              <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
            </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
          </SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
      <SharePoint:AjaxDelta BlockElement="true" id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription" CssClass="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap" runat="server">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="ms-pageDescriptionDiv" style="display:none;">
          <span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage">&#160;</span>
        </a>
        <span class="ms-accessible" id="ms-pageDescription">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
        </span>
        <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
          _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout");
        </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
      </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </h1>
```

The result is that the Site title will be on the right side of the screen latohugh i have defined `float:left"` for the H1 div, so is there a way to move it to the left just beside the logo ?

[image]

Can anyone advice please, if he know how to do it ?

Comment: Why not simply use CSS? `#pageTitle {position: relative; left: -500px}` or `#pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 20px}`

Comment: #pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 20px} works well, but is this a bad practice to define static pixel numbers?? , as end users might be accessing the application using different screen resolution .can you advice ?

Comment: If it was about an element which is deeper in the DOM and more to the right, bottom parts of the page than it would be dangerous but if it's about the logo and heading, which is on the top left part then there is little that could be screwed, in my opinion.